# How to stop first IF in the Timer Tick?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have an image that needs to go until the end of the canvas to the right and after that, it needs to come back and keep doing it as a loop.
Problem is first condition never stops so once reach the Getleft, It keeps working and the image can't go left.

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar()) <= 1920)
        {
            double x = Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar());
            _wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _wolves.WolvesRightAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            x += 5;
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesRightAvatar(), x);
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar(), x);
        }
        else if (Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar()) >= 0)
        {
            double x = Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar());
            _wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _wolves.WolvesRightAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            x -= 5;
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesRightAvatar(), x);
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar(), x);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your first condition is set to `<=1920`.

So when it first time reached over 1920 and ran the second condition, it become lesser then 1920 **AGAIN**!

That's why it'll always keep alternating between the first and second condition when x is flickering between 1920 and 1925!

Try to make a **additional** global variable denoting the **DIRECTION** of the image and then run the if statements.

```
private bool toRight=true;

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    if(toRight)
    {
        if (Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar()) <= 1920)
        {
            double x = Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar());
            _wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _wolves.WolvesRightAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            x += 5;
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesRightAvatar(),x);  
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar(),x);
        }
        else
        {
            toRight=false;
            double x = Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar());
            _wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _wolves.WolvesRightAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            x -= 5;
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesRightAvatar(), x);
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar(), x);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar()) >= 0)
        {
            double x = Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar());
            _wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _wolves.WolvesRightAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            x -= 5;
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesRightAvatar(), x);
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar(), x);
        }
        else
        {
            toRight=true;
            double x = Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar());
            _wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _wolves.WolvesRightAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            x += 5;
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesRightAvatar(),x);    
            Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar(),x);
        }
    }
}
```

Better yet, you could make the image moving as a method and call it.

```
private bool toRight=true;

private void MoveX(int m)
{
    double x = Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar());
    if(m>0)
    {
        _wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        _wolves.WolvesRightAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        _wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        _wolves.WolvesRightAvatar().Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    x += m;
    Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesRightAvatar(),x);    
    Canvas.SetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar(),x);
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    if(toRight)
    {
        if (Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar()) <= 1920)
        {
            MoveX(5);
        }
        else
        {
            toRight=false;
            MoveX(-5);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Canvas.GetLeft(_wolves.WolvesLeftAvatar()) >= 0)
        {
            MoveX(-5);
        }
        else
        {
            toRight=true;
            MoveX(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much! I was so many days on this! I'm new on coding! Look, the first code didn't work for me and I'm not sure why but the method did work perfectly!

Comment: Glad I can help! Debuger is a great tool! You can run it line by line and you'll see that the x is flickering between 1920 and 1925. Learn how to use it and it will do you great help! Good luck!!!